# Examples of Einstein four-manifolds of negative sectional curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Are there any nontrivial compact Einstein four-manifolds of negative or nonpositive sectional curvature? by nontrivial we mean not quotients of $\mathbb{H}^4$, $\mathbb{C}H^2$, $\mathbb{H}^2\times\mathbb{H}^2$, or $\mathbb{H}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2$. I did some search but couldn't find any.

Comment: I think this is an open problem, and things have not changed since Anderson's survey http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.4830. At some point Anderson claimed the existence of such examples, see http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0310041, but it was later retracted.

Comment: you possibly want to add $H^2\times R^2$ to the list of trivial examples, since the product of a hyperbolic surface and the 2-torus is Kähler-Einstein

Comment: using Dehn filling on cusped hyperbolic manifolds (see the papers of Anderson and Bamler) you can construct plenty of manifolds that admit both Einstein and non-positive sectional curvature metrics, but not simultaneously as far as I understand.

Comment: This post https://mathoverflow.net/a/278198/90655 would be useful.

Comment: An example has been announced by Joel Fine and Bruno Premoselli, see here http://scgp.stonybrook.edu/video_portal/video.php?id=3382

Comment: And the paper just came out: https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.00608

Answer (score 6):

This is answered in this paper, based on a construction of Gromov-Thurston (as commented by @YangMills):

*Fine, Joel; Premoselli, Bruno*, [**Examples of compact Einstein four-manifolds with negative curvature**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/jams/944), J. Am. Math. Soc. 33, No. 4, 991-1038 (2020). [MR4155218](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=4155218) [ZBL1467.53055](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1467.53055).

Answer (score -1):

G. Mostow and Y.-T. Siu, A compact Kahler surface of negative curvature not covered by the ball, Ann. Math. 112 (1980) 321-360

Comment: If memory serves, Mostow-Siu metric is not Einstein. I think there is a conjecture that any Kahler-Einstein surface of negative sectional curvature is covered by $CH^2$.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek I believe it _is_ K-E, as follows from the Calabi conjecture.

Comment: I think the metric coming from the solution of Calabi conjecture need not have negative sectional curvature. The conjecture I mention in the first comment is taken from [Siu, Yum Tong; Yang, Paul Compact Kähler-Einstein surfaces of nonpositive bisectional curvature. Invent. Math. 64 (1981), no. 3, 471–487] whose authors discuss Mostow-Sie example in the introduction.